# How to check fetched data and display result accordingly

Tags: php, mysql

I am completely new to php and MySQL apologies if my question is so naive. I have two tables one is Engines and another one is servicing. Basically the engine is two types 1. In use and 2. Ready for use. The servicing is basically two types A and B. In in use kind of engines the Atype servicing is done quarterly and after 3 Atype servicing Btype is done. Similarly in ready for use engines Atype servicing is done once in a year and after 3 years b Type is done. I have fetched data for a particular engine and need to see when it is due for servicing and what type of servicing.

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$check = "SELECT a.engtype, a.slno, b.sertype,b.serdate 
FROM engines a INNER JOIN servicing b ON a.slno=b.slno WHERE b.slno='$slno'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$check);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["engtype"];
    echo $row["slno"];
    echo $row["sertype"];
    echo $row["serdate"];
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Actually I get these results inside a table. My requirement is that after fetching the data from MySQL table I want to intimate the type of servicing and next due date based on the last three servicing of that engine. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What've you tried so far? You'll likely need to group the engines, and compare the last three `serdate`. Whats the requirement exactly? Show some examples, and some code on what you tried.

Comment: The engines are grouped only on basis of in use and ready for use. I fetched the data in a table and tried to compare the sertype but somehow I feel like I have reached the dead end there.

Comment: I agree, can you give us some kind of table of query results, so that we can see.

Comment: When I use limit in my MySQL statement i was able to get only last 3 entries of the servicing from database my problem is I don't know how to compare each rows of table data or say type of servicing and date and servicing for that matter.

Comment: Just `var_dump($result)` and post it here, so that we can see what we are dealing with.

Comment: I'm giving you the var_dump of $row for more clarity. {["Usetype"]=>"in use" ["slno"]=>"1234" ["sertype"]=>"Atype" ["serdate"]=>"2017-01-03"}{["Usetype"]=>"in use" ["slno"]=>"1234" ["sertype"]=>"Atype" ["serdate"]=>"2017-04-03"}.... Here I've given you the result shown for a particular engine serial number, two a type servicing was done on 03 jan 2017 and 03 Apr 2017. What I want here is to intimate the user that next servicing will be A type servicing and it's due on 03 Jul 2017, after 03 Jul 2017 it should intimate that the  engine is due for b type servicing on 03 Oct 2017.Hope I'm clear.